# UAV Waypoint Follower doesn't react on the input waypoints

Tags: matlab, simulation

I'm passing a vector of 3-dimensional values [x, y, z] as an array of waypoints (navigationModel example from [mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/uav/ug/approximate-high-fidelity-uav-model-with-guidance-model.html) pathFollowing.slx). Also i send UAV position and angles data to FlightGear via UDP to visualize the movement.
It works almost fine but i'm always starting at the exact same location and it doesn't matter which first waypoint i'll put in a vector.
So i have two questions:

1. How can i specify exact location from where i want to follow my path?
2. Do the waypoints have to be absolute or relative from some initial location?

It seems that waypoints should be in UTM Coordinates (Easting and Northing) - so they should be converted to Longitude and Altitude after all physics calculations before sending them to FlightGear. But whatever the values i would put in a vector of waypoints it always starts from one place which coordinates i don't know.
Maybe someone already was facing same issue.

upd: It seems to be impossible to pass a value higher than 2000 or -2000. Are there any ways to avoid that?

Comment: Also: the input for Waypoints is in the block called UAV Waypoint Follower